# Does a child object lose its unique properties after casting back and forth between a parent class

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, orientation

Consider the following classes:

```
public class Phone {
    private boolean has3g;

    public boolean has3g() {
        return has3g;
    }

    public void setHas3g(boolean newVal) {
        has3g = newVal;
    }
}

public class Blackberry extends Phone {
    private boolean hasKeyboard;

    public boolean hasKeyboard() {
        return hasKeyboard;
    }

    public void setHasKeyboard(boolean newVal) {
        hasKeyboard = newVal;
    }
}
```

If I was to create an instance of `Blackberry`, cast it to a `Phone` object and then cast it back to `Blackberry`, would the original `Blackberry` object lose its member variables? E.g:

```
Blackbery blackbery = new Blackberry();
blackbery.setHasKeyboard(true);

Phone phone = (Phone)blackbery;

Blackberry blackberry2 = (Blackberry)phone;

// would blackberry2 still contain its original hasKeyboard value?
boolean hasKeyBoard = blackberry2.hasKeyboard();
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened when you did?

Comment: I did try it and it worked fine

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Casting doesn't change the underlying object at all - it's just a message to the compiler that it can treat an `A` as a `B`.

It's also not necessary to cast an `A` to a `B` if `A extends B`, i.e. you don't need to cast a subtype to its supertype; you only need the cast if it's from a supertype to a subtype

Answer (score 9):

> If I was to create an instance of Blackberry, cast it to a Phone
>   object and then cast it back to Blackberry, would the original
>   Blackberry object lose its member variables?

You have instantiated a `Blackberry`. This will remain a `Blackberry` until the it is GCed.
When you cast it to `Phone` you are not changing the fact that the type is `Blackberry`. You are just treating it as a `Phone` i.e. you have only access to its generic properties (that of `Phone`).
The extended properties of `Blackberry` are no longer visible despite the fact that the concrete instance is still a `Blackberry` and you can successfully cast it back to access the `Blackberry` properties.